# Accessing state from context which is updated using useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I have a context for my application which updates the userInfo inside useEffect() like this:

```js
const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setuser] = useState({});
    const [selectedChat, setselectedChat] = useState();
    const [chats, setchats] = useState([]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
        if (!userInfo) {
            navigate('/');
        } else {
            setuser(userInfo);
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <ChatContext.Provider
            value={{ user, setuser, selectedChat, setselectedChat, setchats, chats }}
        >
            {children}
        </ChatContext.Provider>
    );
};
const ChatState = () => {
    return useContext(ChatContext);
};
export { ChatState };
export default ChatProvider;
```

And I am accesing the user in another component like this:

```js
const AllChats = () => {
    const { user, setselectedChat, selectedChat, setchats, chats } = ChatState();
    const toast = useToast();

    const fetchChats = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` },
            };
            const { data } = await axios.get('/api/chat/allChats', config);
            console.log(data);
            setchats(data);
        } catch (error) {
            toast({
                title: 'Error occurred',
                description: 'Failed to load chats',
                status: 'error',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: 'top',
            });
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchChats();
    }, []);

    return <div>{user.token}</div>;
};
```

I am able to see the `user.token` value on the screen which is written inside `return` statement, but inside the useEffect's fetchChat() call, it is not able to access `user.token` value.
[image]

Probably because both updating of state and accessing is done inside useEffect, not sure. What could be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that you are trying to use the token inside `AllChats` before it has been fetched in `ChatProvider`. The solution is to update `AllChats` to wait for the token.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        // only call `fetchChats` when there is a token
        if (user.token) {
            fetchChats();
        }
       // run this effect when the token changes
    }, [user.token]);
```

Comment: oh okayy, this works bro, thanks. Now that I know how to solve it seems so easy. xd